# Is there a way to use the cygwin package manager without updating current packages?

Tags: cygwin, package-management

I've recently had the need to install a package from ports, but I noticed that it automatically marked many packages to be upgraded. Since I only needed one package, it was an extremely annoying effect, and I had to manually mark them as `keep`.

Is there a way to make it not upgrade by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the upper right, click on the `Keep` radio button, then select the package(s) you want to install. Click on the `View` button until you see the Pending View. Only the packages you selected should be shown. Click `Next>` and proceed as usual.